# Python update Linux (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: linux, python-3.x, debian, raspberry-pi

I am trying to upgrade my Python 3.2.4 to the newer 3.3.1 on my Raspberry Pi using the Raspian Wheezy Distro, but for some reason this won't work. I only need it to use the new ipaddress module introduced, however, this is giving me some issues. I am not getting any errors, just the entire proccess doesn't seem to work with the Pi.

I have tried :

```
apt-get install python3
apt-get update python-3.2.4
```

Nothing is giving me any luck, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try `apt-get install package=version`.